# Stream File in Azure App Service lost bytes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a very unusual problem in when I try to Stream file with ASP.NET core and ASP.NET full framework.

I have been trying with  different code samples which work in my local environment and in my local IIS 7. However these code samples when executed in an App Service does not work well. It is impossible to download a  complete file. In every execute, my file(s) lose  a few bytes resulting in corrupted files (upon download).

As I have tried multiple code samples am not providing the code snippets here.The code samples were picked up from either stackoverflow or official documentation.

Comment: About that code on StackOverflow, did you find it in the question or in the answer? Care to share some code with us? Not sure what you expect from us otherwise.

Comment: We host a pretty big service that allows downloads of files in App Service. Works fine for us, so there is probably something wrong with your code.  As evilSnobu said, we kinda need to see some of your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically my code has this:

```
try
{
     WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
     WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
     Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     //...
}
catch (Exception)
{
     MessageBox.Show("There was a problem downloading the file");
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost("Document")]
 [Produces("application/octet-stream")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromBody]DownloadDmsRequest data)
 {
```

If I would receive the stream in a MemoryStream, my file would  download  completely.
I did the test, of downloading the file in memory and after uploading that file to the blob storage, and the file  uploaded successfully without problems.